# Can users see db column values if I do not render them in the blade view for Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, hide

If I was to pull a db row that has a question and the answer to the question but I don't render the answer on the blade view, can a user still use his/her browser to see the answer or other columns of the db row? I am specifically using Laravel and Eloquent.

I would appreciate it a lot if someone could answer this and if it is possible to see the data, how can I go about preventing it?

Any help and or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't render the data in the Blade with `{{ }}` then there is no way it is being shown to the user. The user can only see what you "print" in your HTML that you are going to serve the user, so if you don't add that to your HTML, then the user will not see it.

More info about it on the [Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-data)